# How to change swiper-pagination-bullet background in ionicv4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am facing problem to change slider bullets in **Ionic v4**

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  --bullet-background: red;
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried with `--bullet-background-active` as well?

Comment: Please try this: 
`ion-slides {
    --bullet-background: red;
    --bullet-background-active: rebeccapurple;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet{ background-color:red;}
```

or

```
.swiper-pagination-bullet{ background:red;}
```

This will work fine.